# The making of a well-fed army

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story, geography

> The formation of our crew has been a long process. It has taken weeks of travel to find the best people for each and every job, but we are finally nearing the end of the recruitment stage with only one vital position unfilled.
>
> At first, we of course needed a strong leader. On a distant island chain we found a ruler who is renowned for his wisdom and judgment.
>
> Naturally, we also needed someone with the necessary military acumen to command our troops. We had to sail over 2000 km before we finally secured a high-ranking officer with the necessary combat experience.
>
> There was also the question of feeding our troops. Definitely a position not to be taken lightly – a well-fed army is certain to crush an equally strong but malnourished one. It took well over 4000 km of travel before we came across someone with the nutritional expertise required to prepare our troops' meals.
>
> There is still one important position left to be filled. We need someone to prepare the bread for our soldiers, preferably someone with experience of cooking delicious desserts as well.

How far do you think we have to travel to find our missing crew member?

Comment: the use of "over" as in "over 2000 km" probably increases the number of possible answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see...

The leader is

> Solomon, so this references the Solomon Islands. He's known for his wisdom.

The army leader might then be

> John Marshall, a British captain and fighter during the Revolutionary and Napoleonic Wars. This references the Marshall Islands, roughly 2200km away from the Solomon Islands.

The army-feeder is

> the cook, so this references the Cook Islands, roughly 4400km away from the Marshall Islands.

The bread and dessert maker is

> the baker, so this references [Baker Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker_Island), an uninhabited atoll in the Pacific Ocean.

As per

> le Google, you'd have to travel [3000 kilometres](https://www.google.ca/search?q=distance+from+cook+islands+to+baker+island&rlz=1C1CHBD_enCA715CA715&oq=distance+from+cook+islands+to+baker+island&aqs=chrome..69i57.8654j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to find your missing crew member!

Comment: Lol, you waste no time, do you? Nice work.

Comment: Thanks very much @jafe, this was a fun one to research! Great puzzle! :)

Comment: Was it "island chain" that gave it away?

Comment: @jafe That was a big help; I actually originally had my military answer for that leader but once I found what I knew had to be the correct answer (and then realized the scale of geographic locations I was looking for based on the distances), the search was simplified.

Comment: @jafe This was also a really informative puzzle, since I didn't really know that the answers above were that far away! I think I thought the world was _a lot_ smaller! (So thank you for posing this!)